# How to get the "typeof" in JavaScript for a json message

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

When i try to get the type of an element using the below code it works.

```
var bodyContent = JSON.parse(response.content);

response.content  = typeof bodyContent.CompanyList.Company.Name;
```

Output response for above was String

Whereas if i try it in the below approach this does not work for the same JSON message. Please help

```
var bodyContent = JSON.parse(response.content);

var nameHolder = "CompanyList.Company.Name";

response.content  = typeof bodyContent[nameHolder];
```

Output  was undefined

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's a nested object, you can't just pass a period delimited name and have it recursively drill down the tree (you'll have to implement that yourself).

It's the difference between

```
bodyContent["CompanyList"]["Company"]["Name"]; // former
```

and

```
bodyContent["CompanyList.Company.Name"]; // latter
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this issue.

You have to parse the `nameHolder` path. Reference: [`Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

or use `eval` but I'll not write about this since it's not a good practise.

Answer (score -2):

It looks for a property called "CompanyList.Company.Name".
This works:

```
var bodyContent = JSON.parse(response.content);
var list = "CompanyList";
var company = "Company";
var name = "Name";
response.content  = typeof bodyContent[list][company][name];
```